# Returning an array of promises for Promise.all using filter not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I have an array of objects and for each I execute a promise. Then, if all resolve, I expect to get a `.then` call in `Promise.all`. Problem is that with the following example I only get the output

> All done in approach 2

I think the following code is pretty much explanatory but, in a nutshell, what I'm doing is:

1. Declare 3 objects as `vals` and I want to create a promise based on each.
2. Approach 1: use `vals.map` to get an array of promises based on `vals`
3. Approach 2: iterate through `vals` using a `for` and push a new promise in each iteration.

What's wrong with this code and why is it working only for approach 2?

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

let vals = [
    {
        name: "name1"
    },
    {
        name: "name2"
    },
    {
        name: "name3"
    }
];

function newPromise(obj) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => Promise.resolve(obj.name))
}

/**
 * Approach 1: use .map function to get an array of promises
 */

let promises = vals.map((item) => newPromise(item));
Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => console.log("All done in approach 1"))
    .catch(() => console.log("Error in approach 1"));

/**
 * Approach 2: iterate through vals using a for an push a new promise for the promises array
 */

let promises2 = [];
for (let i = 0 ; i < vals.length; i++) {
    promises.push(newPromise(vals[i]));
}
Promise.all(promises2)
    .then(() => console.log("All done in approach 2"))
    .catch(() => console.log("Error in approach 2"));
```

I'm using node 8.9.1 with ES6 (native Promises).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two slight errors which are gumming up the works and confusing things.

First off, your second approach *shouldn't* work because you accidentally had it pushing them to `promises` for the second approach instead of `promises2`, so you're doing `Promise.all()` with an empty array, which is why it worked.

Then, the reason both don't work because of how you're creating the promises. You were nesting `Promise.resolve()` inside `new Promise()`, which doesn't work. You could use either:

```
return new Promise(resolve => resolve(obj.name));
```

or

```
return Promise.resolve(obj.name);
```

Those are equivalent. Having them inside, you never called the proper `resolve()` function in `new Promise()`, so nothing ever actually resolved.

```js
let vals = [
    {
        name: "name1"
    },
    {
        name: "name2"
    },
    {
        name: "name3"
    }
];

function newPromise(obj) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(obj.name))
}

/**
 * Approach 1: use .map function to get an array of promises
 */

let promises = vals.map((item) => newPromise(item));
Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => console.log("All done in approach 1"))
    .catch(() => console.log("Error in approach 1"));

/**
 * Approach 2: iterate through vals using a for an push a new promise for the promises array
 */

let promises2 = [];
for (let i = 0 ; i < vals.length; i++) {
    promises2.push(newPromise(vals[i]));
}
Promise.all(promises2)
    .then(() => console.log("All done in approach 2"))
    .catch(() => console.log("Error in approach 2"));
```

Comment: omg... I can't believe I missed those details even in this small demo! Thanks! That's totally my mess...

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your `newPromise` function. Try to remove `Promise.`.

For the second approach, you also have to push on the right array : `promises2`

```js
let vals = [
    {
        name: "name1"
    },
    {
        name: "name2"
    },
    {
        name: "name3"
    }
];

function newPromise(obj) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(obj.name))
}

/**
 * Approach 1: use .map function to get an array of promises
 */

let promises = vals.map((item) => newPromise(item));
Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => console.log("All done in approach 1"))
    .catch(() => console.log("Error in approach 1"));

/**
 * Approach 2: iterate through vals using a for an push a new promise for the promises array
 */

let promises2 = [];
for (let i = 0 ; i < vals.length; i++) {
    promises2.push(newPromise(vals[i]));
}
Promise.all(promises2)
    .then(() => console.log("All done in approach 2"))
    .catch(() => console.log("Error in approach 2"));
```